# What's the difference between creating a UNIQUE index as "index" or as "constraint" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, constraints, unique

When creating an index over a column that is going to be UNIQUE (but not the primary key of the table), SQL server let's me choose a few options:

1) I can choose for it to be a Constraint or an Index.
I'm guessing this means that if I set it as constraint, it won't use it when querying, only when writing. However, the only efficient way I can think of for SQL Server to enforce that constraint is by actually building an index. What is the use for this option?

2) Also, if I set it as "index", it let's me specify that it should ignore duplicate keys.
This is the most puzzling for me...
I again guess it means the opposite of constraint. It probably means "use it when querying, but don't even check when writing".
But then why would I set it as UNIQUE?
I'm guessing there are some optimizations SQL Server can do, but i'd like to understand it better.

Does anyone know what exactly SQL Server does with these options?
What's the use case for setting an index to be Unique, but ignore duplicate keys?

NOTE: This is for SQL Server 2000

---

**EDIT:** According to what you said, however... If I create a Constraint, will it be used to speed up queries that filter using the fields in the constraint?

Thanks!

Comment: I have always wondered about this difference. The difference between a unique index and a unique constraint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `UNIQUE` constraint is part of the ISO/ANSI SQL standard, whereas indexes are not because the Standard is implementation agnostic. SQL Server, in common with most SQL DBMSs, will use an index to implement a `UNIQUE` constraint.

Arguably, using `UNIQUE` rather than index in a SQL script is *slightly* more portable but as always the proprietary syntax should not be ruled out if it provids opportunities for optimization etc.

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server will build an index to implement UNIQUE constraints.  You can see a reference to the unique index that is used to enforce unique constraints in the [sys.key_constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174321.aspx) view (in 2005 — sorry, I don't know the 2000 equivalent).  But both versions will use the index when querying.

The difference is that if you create an index you have more control over how it's built.  In particular, you can include additional columns that may be looked up frequently along with the key.

Both options will allow you to "ignore duplicate keys" on *existing* data, but both will raise an error if you attempt to insert a *new* value that duplicates an existing one.

Answer (score 2):

There is no practical difference between a unique constraint and a unique index other than the fact that the unique constraint is also listed as a constraint object in the database.

Comment: There is some advantage though to marking something as a unique key rather than a unique index, in that database tools like ORMs will notice the unique keys, and may take advantage of them. Unique Keys are almost always minimal, and thus "candidate keys", while unique indexes may regular (perfomance increasing) indexes so marked because they happen to include all columns of a unique key (making them "super keys"), and by marking the index as unique SQL Server can take advantage of that fact in query optimization.

Comment: Kevin: a unique key is either a primary key or a unique constraint. In SQL SQL server unique constraints are implemented using an index. The domain describes if something needs to be unique, unrealted to performance (that's simply a side-effect)

Comment: Indeed, I meant to say unique constraint everywhere were I asaid "unique key". My post was meant to point out the semantic difference, even if SQL server treats them identically. A future version of SQL Server could potentially implement unique contraints in some other way which may provide no lookup benefit, so it is best to use actual unique indexes if the goal is perfomance (as a rule of thumb these are "superkeys") and a unique constaint if the goal is data integrety (usually applies to "candidate keys", since anything else is wasteful).

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN, there are no significant differences between creating a unique index thru a unique constraint, or explicitly creating using CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement. In both the cases, data is validated for uniqueness in the same way, and also the query optimizer does not treat them any differently. As good practice, use unique constraint if data integrity is the goal, other wise use CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement directly.

[Here](http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/unique-and-non-unique-indexes-part-37.html) is an excellent article and a video explaining the difference between both the approaches.